# Python load JSON only loads part of a file

Tags: python, json

This is a simple code example:

```
import json  
f = open("somefile.json")  
d = json.load(f)  
print d 
# output:   
f.seek(0)  
l = f.readlines()  
print l
```

**output**

```
{u'95659045': {u'90': False}}
['{"95659045": {"1": false}, "95659045": {"90": false}}']
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html?highlight=json%20load#json.load) suggests, that the whole file should be loaded.

I honestly have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same key twice '95659045', so the second occurrence overwrite the first.

Comment: That's it ! THANK YOU SO MUCH T_T